# Debugging react.js apps written in Typescript directly from VS code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

Is it possible? For example, i want to be able to set a breakpoint in my component, hit it from chrome, and inspect state, props, methods etc.

I have set up the Debugger from chrome extension for VS code, but when i hit a breakpoint, VS code opens the bundle.js file instead of the actual typescript code. I suppose i will need to set up some kind of source mapping, if it's possible?